# Load content from database, then fade in, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I get content from MySQL database and output it into `#content div`.

I want that div to be invisible by default, and smoothly appear after the content has loaded.

I know it's super-easy but for the life of me I can't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQuery you can add

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('div#id_of_div').html("<?php $content; ?>");
});
```

But there are many ways for showing content , you can use `fadeIn("slow")`. to give effect.

You can also use ajax inside `ready` function. It all depends on you and the way you wish to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

load your content via ajax... (url-to-your-result-stuff).... than you can fade in after reveiving the data

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('your-div-selector')
        .hide()
        .load(
            'url-to-your-result-stuff',
            {},
            function() {
                jQuery(this).fadeIn();
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smooth transition use a class "hidden" with the `visiblity` and `opacity` properties instead of the `display` property otherwise the element won't be part of the regular flow of the document when it's hidden and might flicker. The `visibility` property is to support older browsers that don't know about `opacity`. First add the class on you HTML then add the CSS:

```
div.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then you can use the callback when loading the content to show the div again:

```
$('#content').load('contents.php', function() {
  $(this).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great idea, but I'm not quite clear on he syntax. I get data from MySQL and echo it into #content. Could you explain how to attach class "hidden" to #content? I do not load a separate php file.

Comment: just the most basic jQuery.

Comment: Hard to tell how to do it without your php mysql etc. Consider using AJAX since you're using jQuery anyway. All you have to do is output the data to an html or php file and load it how I wrote above. You don't actually need the class, you can just write the default properties on the div css definition itself.